# Showing that a subspace is invariant of a specific dimension.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm studying for a qualifying exam in algebra and I'm slightly stuck on the following problem:

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field, and let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{F}$. Suppose that $p\in\mathbb{F}[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $d$ with $p(A)=O$, where $O$ is the zero linear operator on $\mathbb{F}^n$. For $x\in\mathbb{F}^n$, let $S(x)$ denote the span of the set $\{A^ix:i=0,1,\cdots,\}$.
>
> (a) Show that if $x$ is nonzero, then $S(x)$ is an $A$-invariant subspace of dimension $d$.
>
> (b) Prove that $d$ divides $n$.

I believe part (b) is straightforward:

Because $p(A)=O$, $p$ is a multiple of the minimal polynomial of $A$. Because the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is also a multiple of the minimal polynomial of $A$, the degree $d$ of $p$ divides the degree of the characteristic polynomial of $A$. Since the characteristic polynomial of a matrix has degree equal to the dimension of the vector space, and $\operatorname{dim}(\mathbb{F}^n)=n$, the desired result follows. $\square$

For part (a), I think I can show invariance, but I'm stuck on dimension:

Note that $S(x)$ is $A$-invariant provided $As\in S(x)$ for all $s\in S(x)$. Equivalently, since $S(x)$ is the span of $\{A^ix:i=0,1,\cdots,\}$, then $S(x)$ is $A$-invariant provided $A(A^ix)\in S(x)$ for each $i=0,1,\cdots,$. Since $A(A^ix)=(AA^i)x=A^{i+1}x\in S(x)$, $S(x)$ is in fact $A$-invariant. $\square$

---

Thanks in advance for any help on showing the dimension of $S(x)$, and for any comments/critiques on what I have done already.

Comment: About $b$: No, $q|p$ does not imply $\deg(q)|\deg(p)$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich In general, no, but this isn't a case of $p(x)=q(x)r(x)$, but rather $p(x)=aq(x)$ where $a$ is a scalar, right?

Comment: Also, to make the argument work except for the problem I pointed out above I think you want to note that $p$ _is_ the minimal polynomial...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say there. My counterexample was wrong as I suspected it must be, but I really don't follow your argument for (b). In fact $p=m$, the minimal polynomial, hence $p|\chi$, the characteristic polynomial. Now why does $d$ divide $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT.

Of course, the @TheWildCat and the OP 's proofs cannot be correct because they do not use the fact that $p$ is irreducible....

For b). This exercise is essentially about the polynomials.

I assume that the field $F$ is perfect (if $r\in F[x]$ is irreducible, then its roots in an algebraic extension are simple). cf. the comments below.

Clearly, $p\in F[x]$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$. On the other hand, $\chi_A\in F[x]$ -the characteristic polynomial of $A$- has degree $n$, is a multiple of $p$ and has (up to multiplicity), the same roots $(\lambda_i)_i$ as $p$ -in an algebraic extension $K$-.

The key is that if some $\lambda_i$ is a root of $q\in F[x]$, then $q$ is a multiple of $p$ (because it's irreducible). We deduce that the multiplicities of the $(\lambda_i)_i$, in $\chi_A$, are the same and, consequently, $\chi_A$ is a power of $p$; finally, $d$ divides $n$.

For a) (cf. also the @David C. Ullrich 's comment about this part).

Let $B=A_{|S(x)}$ where $x\not= 0$; clearly $\delta=dim(S(x))\leq d$; then, $s\in F[x]$, the minimal polynomial of $B$ (that is also the minimal polynomial of $x$) divides $\chi_A$ and has degree $\leq \delta$. Thus $s=p$ and $\delta=d$.

Comment: I  suspect you're assuming the following is familiar to the reader: If $E/K$ is a field extension and $p\in K[x]$ is irreducible in $K[x]$ then every zero of $p$ in $E$ is simple. Proof: The euclidean algorithm shows that $\gcd_E(p,p)=\gcd_K(p,p')=1$. Yes?

Comment: @David C. Ullrich , you are right. Yet, this property is valid only if the field $F$ is perfect. Then I must add this condition about $F$ (most fields that appear in practice are perfect; in particular, fields with characteristic $0$).

Comment: I had to look up "perfect field"... It seems to me that my previous comment contains a proof that every field is perfect. That can't be right, or the terminology would not exist. What's the problem with the proof? (Of course $\gcd_E(p,p)$ was a typo for $\gcd_E(p,p')$.)

Comment: @ David C. Ullrich  .  The finite extensions must be separable, that is, "the minimal polynomial of any element is a polynomial with simple roots". There is an example of non-perfect field in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeparableExtension.html

Comment: I don't follow your argument on how $\chi_A$ is in fact a power of $p$. Clearly it's a multiple of $p$, but it seems you're saying, "They have the same roots up to multiplicity, but actually the multiplicities must be the same." Why?

Comment: Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$  with maximal multiplicity (say $t$). At each of the $t$ roots $\lambda$ of $\chi_A$, we can associate a factor $p$ in $\chi_A$; then the multiplicities of the other eigenvalues necessarily are $\geq t$. thus, all the eigenvalues have the same multiplicity $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Since we have $\deg p=d$ and $p(A)=0$, it follows straightforward that $A^d $ can be written in terms of $\mathrm{Id} , A, A^2 ,\dotsb ,A^{d-1} $.

Comment: So the dimension is no more than $d$; how do you get the other inequality?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Because of the irreducibility of $p$, $x,Ax, A^2 x,\dotsb ,A^{d-1} x$ must be linearly independent.

Comment: How's that? I maybe believe that $I,A,\dots,A^{p-1}$ are independent...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich If not, we can reduce the irreducible polynomial $p$ in the space $S(x)$.

Comment: What does it mean to "reduce $p(x)$ in the space $S(x)$"? Yes, the restriction of $A$ to $S(x)$ satisfies a polynomial of smaller degree. So what?

Comment: Ah right. Say $A_S$ is the operator on $S(x)$ defined by $A$ and $m$ is the minimal polynomial of $A_S$. Since $p(A_S)=0$, $m|p$.